# Express/Jade TypeError

Tags: express, pug

I have Mongo set up and all I am doing is in index.jade, looping through a list of meals.

--app.js--

/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

```
var express = require('express')
mongoose = require('mongoose')
, routes = require('./routes')
, meal = require('./routes/meal')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/new', meal.new);

app.get('/meals', meal.getMeals)
app.post('/meals', meal.add)

app.get('')
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

--meals.js--


var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/nutritionTracker")

var MealSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
mealId: Number,
mealType: String,
mealDetails: String
}),

Meals = mongoose.model('Meals', MealSchema);


/*
* New meal.
*/

exports.new = function(req, res){
res.render('new');
};

/*
* Insert new meal.
*/

exports.add = function(req, res){

var meal = req.body;

new Meals({
mealId: 1,
mealType: meal.mealType,
mealDetails: meal.mealDetails
}).save(function (err, docs) {
if (err) res.render("Error")
});
res.render('new');
};

/*
* Get all meals.
*/

exports.getMeals = function(req, res){
Meals.find({}, function(err, docs) {
res.render('index', { meals: docs });
});
};
```

--index.jade--

extends layout

```
block content
table.table.table-striped
thead
tr
th Meal Type
th Meal Details
tbody
each meal in meals
tr 
td #{meal.type}
td #{meal.details}

a(href="/new", class="btn btn-primary btn-lg") Add Meal
```

I keep getting this error:

TypeError: ...\views\index.jade:10 8| th Meal Details 9| tbody > 10| each meal in meals 11| tr 12| td #{meal.type} 13| td #{meal.details} Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from what you posted but you might want to make sure that your query actually brings back what you expect. You have an `err` variable passed in the callback that you don't use.

Try with this and let me know what it brings back:

```
exports.getMeals = function(req, res){
    Meals.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        console.log(err, docs);
        if(err) return res.send(500, {
            error: err
        });
        res.render('index', { meals: docs });
    });
}
```

`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` is probably jade complaining that it can't loop through the results because they are not valid (array).

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely resides in your rendering code, where your code modifies the response with jade. This is where the variables are passed to jade, I would guess that recent updates to jade and express might be causing the problem.

I was getting these errors when I updated my jade and express. I looked at the [examples in the jade repository.](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/tree/master/examples) In latest jade@0.26.3 and express@3.4.8 the server renders a jade file with data like so:

```
server.get('/', function(req, res) {
  return res.render('index.jade', {
    title: 'Blog',
    description: 'Your Page Description',
    users: users
  });
});
```

Using `return res.render('index.jade', {meals:meals});` as being the difference from older versions.